# Should complex number multiplication be equivalent to a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, linear-transformations

I have been thinking about viewing the geometric intuition of multiplying two vectors as applying linear transformations to one of the operands. Apropos of multiplying by the imaginary unit $i$ to perform a CCW rotation of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians on a vector.

Let's say I have two complex numbers $v_1$ and $v_2$ written in polar form below.

$$
\begin{aligned}
v_1 &= 3\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{6} + i\sin\frac{\pi}{6}\right) &= \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
3/2
\end{bmatrix}\\
v_2 &= 4\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{3} + i\sin\frac{\pi}{3}\right) &= \begin{bmatrix}
2\\
2\sqrt{2}
\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

One can obtain their product by multiplying their moduli and summing their arguments.

$$
v_1v_2 = 12\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{2} + i\sin\frac{\pi}{2}\right) =
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\12
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Shouldn't this be the same as performing two linear transformations on $v_2$? A rotation by $\frac{\pi}{6}$ radians and a scaling by 3? (I don't think the order should matter for a rotation and scaling.) When I do this, I do not get the same result as above.

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \begin{bmatrix}
3\cos\frac{\pi}{6} & -3\sin\frac{\pi}{6}\\
3\sin\frac{\pi}{6} & 3\cos\frac{\pi}{6}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
2\sqrt{2}
\end{bmatrix}\\
=&\,2\begin{bmatrix}
3\cos\frac{\pi}{6}\\
3\sin\frac{\pi}{6}
\end{bmatrix} + 2\sqrt{3}\begin{bmatrix}
-3\sin\frac{\pi}{6}\\
3\cos\frac{\pi}{6}\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
=&\,\begin{bmatrix}
6\cos\frac{\pi}{6} - 6\sqrt{3}\sin\frac{\pi}{6}\\
6\sin\frac{\pi}{6} + 6\sqrt{3}\cos\frac{\pi}{6}\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
=&\,\begin{bmatrix}0\\12\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$

Something is wrong with my intuition here. I would expect these to be equivalent.

**EDIT:** Originally I had $\sin\frac{\pi}{3} = 2\sqrt{2}$. It should be $2\sqrt{3}$. Corrected. **This solves the problem.**

Comment: You don't multiply the matrices correctly. The first equality with the matrices is wrong.

Comment: $v_2$ should be $(2,2\sqrt{3})$, not $(2,2\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Ahhh, yup. Shoot.

Comment: I'm not sure if this adds anything, but viewing complex numbers $z_1,z_2$ as $r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ and $r_2e^{i\theta_2}$ can be used to actually visualize the scaling and rotation.

Comment: You could drop the vector and work entirely with matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$, which are isomorphic to the complex numbers $a+ib$. As you’ve found, these matrices represent scaled rotations.